# Submit Button breaks HTML render with Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on a simple site, just for learning some Django. I'm having troubles when trying to submit a form in order to search for something in my database. All the site is working fine, but when I look for something in that request, the web explorer just shows the raw HTML instead of rendering it.

Here I share my view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from AppFinal.models import Usuario, Direccion, Estudio
from AppFinal.forms import UsuarioFormulario,

def buscarUsuario(request):
    return render(request, 'AppFinal/buscarUsuario.html')

def buscar(request):
    if request.GET['nombre']:
        nombre=request.GET['nombre']
        usuarios = Usuario.objects.filter(nombre__icontains=nombre)        
        return render(request, 'AppFinal/resultadoBusqueda.html', {'usuarios': usuarios}, {'nombre': nombre})    
   else:
        respuesta = 'No enviaste datos'
        return render(request, 'AppFinal/resultadoBusqueda.html', {'respuesta':respuesta})

def resultadoBusqueda(request):
    return render(request, 'AppFinal/resultadoBusqueda.html')
```

This is the URLs file:

```
from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
from django.urls import path
from AppFinal import views
import AppFinal


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.inicio, name='Inicio'),        
    path('buscarUsuario', views.buscarUsuario, name= 'buscarUsuario'),        
    path('resultadoBusqueda', views.resultadoBusqueda , name= 'resultadoBusqueda'),
    path('usuario', views.usuario, name= 'usuario'),
    path('buscar/', views.buscar),
]
```

This is the HTML where you look for a specific item in the database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/AppFinal/buscar/" method="GET"> {% csrf_token %}    
    <input type="string", name= "nombre", id= "nombre">
    <input type="submit", value="Buscar"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the HTML that is suposed to show the result of the search, and that is not rendering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if usuarios %}
    <p>Estamos buscando el: {{nombre}}</p>    
    <ul>
        {% for usuario in usuarios %}
        <li> {{usuario.nombre}}</li>
        <li> {{usuario.apellido}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>    
    {% else %}    
    <p>No hay datos con esta descripcion.</p>    
    {% endif %}    
    <p style="color: red;">{{respuesta}}</p>     
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, here I share a picture so you can see how it is 'not rendering' (although the code seems to work, because there you can see the result of the search in a list)

[Search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQUGh.jpg)

Comment: Whats the URL on the picture?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.
It was a typing error when defining the context in the views file.

Here is the wrong line:

```
       return render(request, 'AppFinal/resultadoBusqueda.html', {'usuarios': usuarios}, {'nombre': nombre})
```

It should be:

```
       return render(request, 'AppFinal/resultadoBusqueda.html', {'usuarios': usuarios, 'nombre': nombre})
```